# Facing Facebook place checkin issue when adding my own places

Tags: android

I have added my own places in places class for check-in but getting this error

`**API response: {"error": { "message":"(#) Requires a valid Place Page ID:,"type: "OAuthException", "code:100}}**`

how do I get the `PageID` of my own places?.I am unable to find any solution .I have studied the Facebook document but unable to understand what exactly I need to do.even I have tried

```
this code in FQL Query class
**SELECT page_id,latitude,longitude FROM place WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, "76.8036676", "30.7323298")<250**
```

but not getting any solution.

Any help will be highly appreciated.